# Inserting data of multiple textbox in one database filed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
function generateRow() {
var d=document.getElementById("div");
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='[Post][textbox1][" + i + "]'>";
i = i + 1;
}
```

```
<?php $this->Form->input('textbox1',array(
                'type' => 'textbox',
                'label' => false,
                'required')); ?>
              <div id="div"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/>
```

**Html For Textbox1**

```
<div class="input textbox"><input name="data[Post][textbox1]"
 required="required"type="textbox" id="PostTextbox1"/></div>
```

When I click on "Add" button, It generates new text box with `name="[Post][textbox1][1]"`
I can enter data in that box, but

**Issue 1**

When I again click on Add button It will reset all textbox and I have to enter those data again

**Issue 2**

```
$tbVal = $this->request->data['Post']['textbox1'];
$inn = implode(',',$tbVal);
```

When I use this code to implode data from textbox, it is showing only first data

Comment: you need to append HTML instead of using innerHTML for 1st issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example based on the first answer and my answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
function generateRow() 
{

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", "data[Post][textbox][" + i + "]");
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);

    i = i + 1;

}
</script>

<form>

<div id="fooBar" class="input textbox">
    <input name="data[Post][textbox][0]" required="required" type="textbox" id="PostTextbox1"/>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/>
<input type="submit" >
</form>

<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

You have to use DOM manipulation javascript functions to not reset your text values and use proper name for the text boxes

Answer (score 1):

you have reset all data in div `document.getElementById("div")` there for it reset all data in textbox.

try :

```
//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");
//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("value", type);
element.setAttribute("name", type);
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
//Append the element in page (in span).
foo.appendChild(element);
```

on button click

Answer (score 0):

Regarding issue 2

This code:

```
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='[Post][textbox1][" + i + "]'>";
```

have to be

```
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='data[Post][textbox1][" + i + "]'>";
```

Comment: I did as you suggest and now it is bringing me empty array

Comment: Though I added values it brings this array 
[textbox1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                )

Comment: well.. you array is like that data[Post][textbox1][0] , data[Post][textbox1][1]...  do you want to be in different format?